# VSCode autoformat going to 2 spaces instead of 4

Tags: visual-studio-code

Whenever I let vscode autoformat my code, it formats to 2 spaces instead of 4, even though apparently the default is 4 spaces, and I have not touched the settings.json

Editor.tabsize also shows 4.

In the bottom right hand corner, its shows spaces: 4, but after autoformatting, it shows spaces: 2, and will revert itself back to 2 no matter how many times I change it to 4.

Anyone know what's going on.  This is happening with Ruby, if that matters.

Also, does anyone know of an alternate indenter/autoformatter for VScode?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I think that you might have a problem with "Auto Detect Indentation". You should try to turn it off and see if that helps.

```
// The number of spaces a tab is equal to. This setting is overriden based on the file contents when `editor.detectIndentation` is on.
"editor.tabSize": 4,

// When opening a file, `editor.tabSize` and `editor.insertSpaces` will be detected based on the file contents.
"editor.detectIndentation": false
```

Comment: `how to do it?` Answer is excellent, please bother to add some guide it is telling perfectly `what to do`, but everybody would not get `how to do it`

Comment: `Ctrl` + `,` (comma) opens the settings tab. Use the search bar there.

Comment: I did that - still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: I just HATE this IDE from all of my heart. Two hours now I can't fix this... I indent the file with 4 spaces and when I hit autoformatting shortcut it is back to 2.... i have no Idea what the hell is going on..

Comment: I think this is a bug from vs code

Comment: @LachezarRaychev - it's likely you have an extension, such as Prettier, installed that is overriding VSCode's built-in settings.  Find the configuration for that extension and configure your indentation settings there.

Comment: Thanks @LachezarRaychev, Prettier was the root cause, and changing "prettier.tabWidth": 4 has done the trick.

Answer (score 21):

For those who could not use above like me, Here is somewhat GUI guide.

Go to setting by pressing = > `CTRL` + `,` (suggested by comment) to open settings or via menue

```
File->Preferences->Settings
```

There you can find both (find `tab size` and `detect indentation`) in search box, like I have shown in following image (see the text 'lets play')

`detect indentation` => uncheck it (turn off)

`tab size` => Set it to 4

How to ? need to visualize? here it is,

**Right click following image and open in new tab see it clearly**

[image]

Comment: You can also use `CTRL` + `,` to open the settings.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this problem using https://editorconfig.org/

```
# EditorConfig is awesome: https://EditorConfig.org

# top-most EditorConfig file
root = true

[*]
indent_style = tab
indent_size = 4
end_of_line = crlf
charset = utf-8
trim_trailing_whitespace = true
insert_final_newline = true
```

Make sure to also install the vs code **extension**!

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that worked for me:

1. Go to Settings
2. In the search bar, type "Prettier: Use Tabs"
3. Make sure this setting is on